# Using curve_fit to fit a parameter that varies with x

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

So I am trying to use Scipy curve_fit to fit the Fuchs-Sondheimer formula to some resistivity (y) against sample thickness (x) data.  The formula looks like this:

y = (rho_0)*(1 + 3l/8x)

Where rho_0 is constant for all x values but l varies for each value of x.

My problem is curve_fit returns a single value for both rho_0 l and I can't fathom how to get it to return different optimum values of l for each x value. I'm twisting my mind trying to write functions within functions but I'm sure theres an easy way of going about this that I'm missing.

Thank you for your help and I hope I've not worded that too confusingly.

Comment: Please provide some code and data, then it will be much easier to help. Right now it is not entirely clear to me what the actual problem is.

Comment: *"Where rho_0 is constant for all x values but l varies for each value of x."* So you mean `y = f(x) = rho_0*(1 + 3*I(x)/(8*x))`?  `curve_fit` requires a model with a finite number of parameters.  It can't find an *arbitrary* function `I(x)`.

Comment: So you have to decide on a parametrized family of functions that defines the possible forms of the function I(x), and then express the function passed to `curve_fit`  in terms of those parameters.

Comment: I see another potential problem. If you have three data points, you will have four parameters to be fitted - and curve_fit will give an error that there are more parameters than data points..